# Exracting first element of list as a plain integer in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I am trying to track  objects via opencv+python module. For the feedback I assign instant positions of objects in a planar space such as x and y coordinates. and i assign the positions to lists like;

```
object1=[]
object2=[]
```

since this objects have different colors such as one red and other green, so if the color is red i consider this as object1 and assign the gravity center coordinates of red object to object1 similarly for object2 so in code look like;

```
        if (29<cv.Get2D(imghsv,centroidy,centroidx)[0]<64): #RGB values ranges
            object1.append((centroidx,centroidy))
        elif (0<cv.Get2D(imghsv,centroidy,centroidx)[0]<19):
            object2.append((centroidx,centroidy))
```

now I want to do some mathematical operations on first elements of my lists 
but whatever i tried to solve my problem i couldnt. i tried;

```
object1.pop(0)+object2.pop(0)
```

but this is making a list while i want to  numerical sum. i stuck here can you give me some hint to solve this?.

Comment: `object1.append((centroidx,centroidy))` the content of your list is tuples. What do you expect to happen when you add them together?

Comment: so i tried this  `int(''.join(map(str, object1[0])))+ int(''.join(map(str, object2[0])))` i expect to sum first elements but it gives me sum of all elements  what i am missing here @njzk2

Comment: [i+j for i,j in zip(object1[0],object2[0])]    ?

Comment: this is still giving me a output with 2 elements while i want only numerically sum of first elements  @Skycc

Comment: 1st element sum like object1[0][0] + object2[0][0] ?

Comment: yes that is it thank you very much :) @Skycc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume the object list itself is holding integer element

```
result = [i+j for i,j in zip(object1[0],object2[0])]
# result[0] access centroidx sum
# result[1] access centroidy sum
```

But the user just interested on centroidx sum, so we can just sum the centroidx

```
result = object1[0][0] + object2[0][0]
```